# Jquery Datepicker function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

[image: unstyled and strange datepicker]I'm trying to get the datepicker to work in firefox using JS.

Here is my simple code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  });
</script>
```

I keep getting the error that datepicker is not a function. What seems to be wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you include the datepicker plugin script? It's not included in jQuery.

Comment: <script> tag shouldn't have a closing part.

Comment: $.datepicker() is not a valid jQuery method.  Are you using an extension or plugin?

Comment: @AbdullahAlemadi Not true at all. <script> is required to have an ending tag in HTML5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: @JonUleis Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need datepicker.js too:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.5.4/datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: it works but this is what I'm getting: an unstyled and strange looking datepicker. Tried adding the css files that come with the downloaded library to no avail. (see the picture I added to my question) cheers